# Is there a way to globally change the appearance of messages in Messages (Beta) for OS X?

Tags: customization, messages

In OS X [Messages (Beta)](http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/messages-beta/), the appearance of a given message thread can be changed by selecting submenu options from the `View > Messages` menu item; but this only applies to the currently displayed message. Is there a way to configure these options as defaults for (all) new threads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
Messages > Preferences > Messages
```

You can set the look and feel for incoming and outgoing messages here.

[image]